# Condition with Classes and ID's in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, class

I have a question about if statement .
I have a page with 4 menu elements and all of them have a content .All of them have a fixed **ID** which is never changed and they all have classes and active menu element has additional classes . So I want to add a picture just for 2 of those elements when they are **active** and **remove** when it's not active

[image]

Can anyone help with **if statement**  for this occasion , I would highly appreciate your help and advise 


Thank you! ;)

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Please split your requirement, make separate searches, assemble all answers, unite them, get your final solution done. Every resource required for solving this question, is already there in SO itself.

Answer (score 1):

For this you will want to use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check whether the element has the `.active` class or not.

`var isActive = $(".someDiv").hasClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

How to research and find answer for your question?

1) Check the element has specific class(s).

```js
console.log($("#a").hasClass('a b c'));
console.log($("#a").hasClass('a b'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="a b"></div>
```

2) Add image to a div. (you can set css background, or add a image tag)

```js
if ($("#a").hasClass('a b')) {
  $("#a").css({
    'background-image': 'url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d26718c…?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)'
  });
}
if ($("#c").hasClass('c')) {
  $("#c").append($('<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d26718c…?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />'));
}
```

```css
.a,
img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="a b"></div>
<br /><br />
<div id="c" class="c"></div>
```

3) While having many div's, decide which menu item should add the image tag.
 * can add a attribute to the menu items indicating the image status
 * or using class/id of the menu ..etc

```js
$(document).on('click', '.menu', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('shouldcontainimage') == 'true') {
    $(".contents").css({
      'background-image': 'url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d26718c…?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1)'
    });
  } else {
    $(".contents").css({
      'background-image': ''
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.contents {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="menu a" shouldcontainimage="false">A</div>
<br />
<div id="b" class="menu b" shouldcontainimage="true">B</div>
<br />
<div id="c" class="menu c" shouldcontainimage="false">C</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="contents"></div>
```